# Remove changed order duplicates in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` representing image comparisons. It looks like this:

```
    f1  s1              f2  s2              s
0   1   bin_n000037_1   1   bin_n000037_1   1.000000
1   1   bin_n000037_1   1   bin_n003202_1   0.484883
2   1   bin_n000037_1   1   bin_n005655_1   0.422175
3   1   bin_n000037_1   1   bin_n002591_1   0.249483
4   1   bin_n000037_1   1   bin_n006038_1   0.248775
... ... ... ... ... ...
270395  1   bin_n009091_1   1   bin_n005261_1   0.000071
270396  1   bin_n009091_1   1   bin_n000316_1   0.000059
270397  1   bin_n009091_1   1   bin_n005382_1   0.000058
270398  1   bin_n009091_1   1   bin_n002629_1   0.000030
270399  1   bin_n009091_1   1   bin_n003807_1   0.000014
```

Every image, identified by `f1` and `s1`, in a folder has been compared to every image, identified by `f2` and `s2`, in the the same folder. I want to

1. Remove every row where the image has been compared to it self.
2. Remove every row where the image comparisons has been repeated, that is, if image `[f1, s1]: [1, bin_n000037_1]` was compared to image `[f2, s2]: [1, bin_n003202_1]`, i want to remove the duplicate row `[f1,s1,f2,s2] = [1, bin_n003202_1, 1, bin_n000037_1]`.

I do do 1) with the code

`df[(df["f1"] != df["f2"]) | (df["s1"] != df["s2"])]`

but how can I do 2) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the column names [`lreshape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to identify the duplicates indices:

```
keep = (pd
   .lreshape(df[(df['f1'] != df['f2']) | (df['s1'] != df['s2'])]
             .reset_index(),
             {'F': ['f1', 'f2'], 'S': ['s1', 's2']})
   .drop_duplicates(subset=['F', 'S'])
   ['index']
)

out = df.loc[keep]
```

With a more meaningful example:

```
# input
   f1 s1  f2 s2    s
0   1  A   1  B  0.1   # identical to 1
1   1  B   1  A  0.1   # identical to 0
2   1  A   1  A  1.0   # self-identical
3   1  A   1  C  0.2
4   1  C   1  B  0.3

# output
   f1 s1  f2 s2    s
0   1  A   1  B  0.1
3   1  A   1  C  0.2
4   1  C   1  B  0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'f1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    's1': ['bin_n000037_1', 'bin_n000037_1', 'bin_n000037_1', 'bin_n000037_1', 'bin_n009091_1', 'bin_n000037_1'],
    'f2': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    's2': ['bin_n000037_1', 'bin_n003202_1', 'bin_n005655_1', 'bin_n002591_1', 'bin_n003807_1', 'bin_n003202_1'],
    's': [1.000000, 0.484883, 0.422175, 0.249483, 0.000014, 0.484883]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("Original:")
print(df)
print("------")

# Remove self-comparisons:
df = df[(df['f1'] != df['f2']) | (df['s1'] != df['s2'])]

# For duplications:
def sort_columns(row):
    return pd.Series(sorted([row['f1'], row['f2']])) 
df[['f1', 'f2']] = df.apply(sort_columns, axis=1)
df.drop_duplicates(['f1', 's1', 'f2', 's2'], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print("After removing duplicates and compared before:")
print(df)
print("------")
```

**Output:**

0nd and 1st same (identical), 1st and 5th are duplication, 5th one was removed because they were compared before in the 1st line.

[image]